# Normal calculations in vertex shader?

Tags: directx, shader, lighting, terrain, normals

I'm using the rastertek framework for terrain generation. I've got the terrain rendered from the vertex shader but I don't know how to calculate the normals in the shader. Theres a function call in one of the classes that generates the normals from the terrain but this only works if the terrain was generated on the cpu. Heres the code for the vertex shader I'm using:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: terrain.vs
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "terrain.fx"

/////////////
// GLOBALS //
/////////////

cbuffer MatrixBuffer
{
    matrix worldMatrix;
    matrix viewMatrix;
    matrix projectionMatrix;
};


//////////////
// TYPEDEFS //
//////////////
struct VertexInputType
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
};

struct PixelInputType
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
};


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Vertex Shader
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
PixelInputType TerrainVertexShader(VertexInputType input)
{
    PixelInputType output;

    input.position.y = input.position.y + terrain(input.position.x,input.position.z);

    // Change the position vector to be 4 units for proper matrix calculations.
    input.position.w = 1.0f;

    // Calculate the position of the vertex against the world, view, and projection matrices.
    output.position = mul(input.position, worldMatrix);
    output.position = mul(output.position, viewMatrix);
    output.position = mul(output.position, projectionMatrix);

    // Calculate the normal vector against the world matrix only.
    output.normal = mul(input.normal, (float3x3)worldMatrix);

    // Normalize the normal vector.
    output.normal = normalize(output.normal);

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Why you want to do that? You want to calculate normals each time vertex shader invokes? I don't think it's a good idea. Why can't u generate all normals with cpu?

Comment: @Acrilige: To save memory bandwidth ... If you are over your memory budget but have spare GPU power such things can be very useful ... equally you may not be over your memory budget but you may find you can jam a load more into your shaders withotu harming performance.  Why not use that?

Comment: I will know, thank you for explanation

Answer (score 4):

Your big problem with generating normals in a shader is that you need knowledge of surrounding vertices.  This is something you can overcome with a geometry shader but not with a vertex shader.  A simple way to calculate the normal is to calculate the polygon normals (take the vector formed from 2 edges and cross product them for the face normal) of all polys that hit the vertex you are looking at and then add them up and normalise.  As such if you haven't got access to a geometry shader the only real solution is to use the CPU.  Even then this is not the best way to calculate the vertex normals.  You may still find it better to use a more complex algorithm yet and that will give you even more problems!  So yeah, CPU or geometry shader ... those are, basically, your options.

Comment: How do I access the transformed vertices though? On the cpu I have a flat plane in an array that I loop through to calculate the normals of, but if I transform the vertices on the gpu then the array values dont get changed from the flat surface and I get lighting as if the terrain was flat.

Comment: why do you need the transformed normal?  Its simply the world matrix multiplied by the normal (make sure the w is 0 for that multiplication though!)

Comment: I already multiply the normal by the world matrix and it doesn't light properly. As for making w = 0, is that input.position.w? I tried that and it didn't change anything.

Comment: No a direction vector should have a w of 0 ... a position vector should have a w of 1 ...

Comment: My normals only have an x,y,z though, should I make the float4?

Comment: I'm only using a 3x3 world matrix, is that why I'm getting incorrect normals?

Comment: By setting w to 0 you effectively do the same with a 4x4 matrix as you would multiplying a 3 vector by a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: I should also add that a 3x3 matrix can only contain rotation (well and scaling) information.  So you cannot translate a 3 vector using a 3x3 matrix multiply.  However as a normal is untranslatable (ie you can only rotate and scale it) that is not a problem.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. So doing that in the vertex shader gives me light as if the terrain was completely flat, and I have a function to calculate the normals properly on the cpu. How would I use that function to calculate the normals from the gpu?

Comment: When you say "flat" do you mean looking like it is faceted (ie really visible polys) or a single lighting colour across the whole landscape? As already stated you'd need to use something like a geometry shader to do it ...

Comment: Its a single lighting color.

Comment: @ExplodingFirework: Then that implies all your normals are the same (0, 1, 0) perhaps?  Basically you need your proper normals and you aren't going to get those without doing another shader or CPU work.  It really is easiest just to use the CPU.

Comment: I know they are all the same, I just dont know how to calculate them correctly. I guess I'll just move the terrain back to the cpu.